# Go net/http request body is always nil

Tags: go

The http request body is always nil. Why is this happening? I am using the gokit toolkit. Below code is part of the handler.

```
    func decodeAddRequest(_ context.Context, r *http1.Request) (interface{}, error) {
    req := endpoint.AddRequest{}
    p, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", p)
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&req)
    return req, err
}
```

My POST JSON request looks like this

```
{
    "title": "test test",
    "complete": false
}
```

And what gets saved to the database is

```
{
    "title": "",
    "complete": false
}
```

The type are:

```
type AddRequest struct {
    Todo io.Todo `json:"todo"`
}

type Todo struct {
    Id       bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    Title    string        `json:"title" bson:"title"`
    Complete bool          `json:"complete" bson:"complete"`
}
```

Comment: @ThunderCat Really new to this but when i format print the request body. This is what it prints out.

&{0xc0001740e0 <nil> <nil> false true {0 0} false false false 0x42b13e0}

Comment: The body does not look nil to me.  Perhaps it's empty.   Add `p, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body); fmt.Printf("%s\n", p)` to see what's in the body.  Show the definition of `models.CreateRequest`.

Comment: This is what got printed out

{        "title": "test test",
        "complete": false
}
ts=2018-10-28T12:56:20.56639Z caller=server.go:105 err=EOF

Comment: @ThunderCat
 type AddRequest struct {
 Todo io.Todo `json:"todo"`
}

type Todo struct {
 Id       bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
 Title    string        `json:"title"  bson:"title"`
 Complete bool          `json:"complete" bson:"complete"`
}

Comment: @ThunderCat CreateRequest is AddRequest in the above example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON is for a todo item, not for a CreateRequest.  Unmasrhal to the todo item:

```
err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&req.Todo)
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot. Can you elaborate on your solution